# Temporary value is freed inconsistency

Tags: rust

Why does this generate a "temporary value is freed" error:

```
    let mut new_string = String::from("test");
    new_string.push_str(
        if true { &format!("{}","ay") } else { "ay" }
    );
```

When this is valid:

```
    let mut new_string = String::from("test");
    new_string.push_str(
        &format!("{}","ay")
    );
```

Playground [Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed5870ce0ff6e9992b380d4ee636127b)

Comment: Temporary lifetimes are [specified to some extent in the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes). The reference isn't completely clear on this particular case, but judging from the behaviour of the compiler it looks like the temporary returned by `format!()` lives until the end of the _block_ in the first case, while it lives until the end of the `push_str()` call in the second case. The "block" in the first case is just the "then" branch of the if-expression.

Comment: The wording in the reference makes it sound like the temporary should live longer in the first case, though: "the tail expression of a block is considered part of the statement that encloses the block"

Comment: Okay, that makes sense...

But then why does this work:
    `new_string.push_str(
        {&format!("{}","ay")}
    );`

Comment: I think the reference is a bit too vague to fully understand temporary lifetimes. I found a fuller explanation [in this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-memory-model/issues/17). The "arena tree" explained there indeed seems to be fully in line with the observed behaviour in all cases you mention.

Answer (score 1):

`format!` returns a `String` (without `&`) and therefore gives you ownership to what it returns. You could say that the current block owns it. It is then dropped at the end of the current block.

In

```
let mut new_string = String::from("test");
new_string.push_str(
    if true { &format!("{}","ay") } else { "ay" }
);
```

this is `{ &format!("{}","ay") }`. At `}` the value is dropped, before `push_str` could use it.

In

```
let mut new_string = String::from("test");
new_string.push_str(
    &format!("{}","ay")
);
```

it lives long enough.

`new_string.push_str( {&format!("{}","ay")} );` works because the curly braces are optimized away.

```
new_string.push_str( {
    let t = &format!("{}","ay");
    t
} );
```

does not work.